# Traceroute RTT latency-jump before and not after transatlantic crossing?

Tags: networking, routing, ping, traceroute, latency

so I did a traceroute from my home-box (situated in Europe) to an US-Server. Now I get a protocol that looks like this:

> 7 er1.ams1.nl.above.net (80.249.208.122)  30.536 ms  32.328 ms  32.315 ms
>
> 8 ae14.cr1.ams10.nl.zip.zayo.com (64.125.21.77)  32.772 ms  32.753 ms  32.858 ms
>
> 9  ae27.cs1.ams10.nl.eth.zayo.com (64.125.27.0)  168.382 ms  166.869 ms  166.805 ms
>
> 10  ae6.cs1.lhr11.uk.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.77)  168.848 ms  168.844 ms  169.118 ms
>
> 11  ae5.cs1.lga5.us.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.126)  169.215 ms  169.076 ms  169.188 ms

Clearly there is a big jump in latency between hop 8 and 9; *however* I can not discern why this jump would occur to be assigned to named hops, when apparently the latency jump should occur between 10 and 11 (from UK to US). Between those however, there is virtually no meaningful increase in latency.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "What am I missing here?" The name of a router does necessarily correspond to it's location?

Comment: hm.. assuming that *nl.eth.zayo.com *uk.eth.zayo.com *us.eth.zayo.com server-names wouldn't be located in the respective locales of their namestrings would be kind of a stretch, wouldn't it? Also, geographically the route would make perfect sense: NL>UK>US. Thanks for your comment though